# “can't convert Symbol into Integer” weird error

Tags: ruby, haml

The is the hash I am working on,

```
a = {
  #...
  :fares => {
    :itinerary_fare => {
      :segment_names=>"C", 
      :free_seats => "6", 
      :fare_for_one_passenger => {
        :free_seats=>"0", 
        :@currency => "TL", 
        :@non_refundable => "false", 
        :@price => "439.0", 
        :@service_fee => "25.0", 
        :@tax => "33.0", 
        :@type => "Y"
      },
      :@currency => "TL", 
      :@non_refundable => "false", 
      :@price => "439.0", 
      :@service_fee => "25.0", 
      :@tax => "33.0", 
      :@type => "C"
    },
    :@currency => "TL", 
    :@tax => "33.0"
  }, 
  #..
}
```

also here another example http://pastebin.com/ukTu8GaG.

The code that gives me headhaches,

```
a[:fares][:itinerary_fare].each do |f|
   puts f[:@price]
end
```

If I write this into console, it gives me "can't convert Symbol into Integer" error. But if I write, `a[:fares][:itinerary_fare][:@price]` it works pretty fine.

The weirdest part is, if I write the code to a haml file

```
%tbody
    -@flights.each do |a|
     %tr.flight
      %td
       -a[:fares][:itinerary_fare].each do |f|
        -puts f[:@price] #Weird stuff happens here
        .prices
         %input{:type=>"radio",:name=>"selectedfight",:value=>"#{a[:id]}"}
          = f[:@price]
         %br
```

It works, it prints the prices to my console, yet it fails at the SAME LINE.

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer file: flights.haml location: [] line: 18
```

This is the most disturbing error I have ever seen, thanks for any help.

Most of the time there are more than 1 `:itinerary_fare`, I have to iterate.

My data can be shown as http://postimage.org/image/6nnbk9l35/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a[:fares][:itinerary_fare]` is a `Hash`. `Hash#each` [yields key-value-pair arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each) to the block.

So, `f` takes e.g. the array `[:@price, "439.0"]` in the block.

Hence you are using a symbol (`:@price`) as an array index. An integer is expected.

In `a[:fares][:itinerary_fare][:@price]` you are giving it as hash key which works of course.

Answer (score -1):

Why did you delete the previous question, that was already *correctly* answered? You could only just updated it with more information. 
As was answered by other user in your previous post you are iterating over the elements in `a[:fares][:itinerary_fare]`. You can see this with:

```
a[:fares][:itinerary_fare].each do |f|
     puts f
end
```

And you dont need a loop, you can use:

```
a[:fares][:itinerary_fare][:@price]
```

If you have more than one :itinerary_fare it will only consider the last one, since it's a key of the hash :fares. Maybe you need an array like (left to minimal of elements):

```
a = {:id=>"1",
    :fares=>{
      :itinerary_fares=>[{:@price=>"439"}, {:@price=>"1000"}]
    }
}
```

and then:

```
a[:fares][:itinerary_fares].each do |f|
    puts f[:@price]
end
```

Comment: i've deleted it because it was posted with my friends SO account accidentally, sorry for any problems